# how to update a varchar in the sqlite database in java

Tags: java, database, sqlite, sql-update

I have a problem with to update a varchar in the sqlite database in java.
when I run this source, than I get a error.
I want String a to update to String b.

This is my source:

```
public void onClick (View v){
String a = "Test1";
String b = "Test2";

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
                 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                 values.put("Level1", b);
                     db.update("Game", values, a, null);
                 db.close();
}
```

And this is my Error:

```
Error updating Level1=Test2 using update Game SET Level1=? WHERE Test1.
```

can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, however, you added `a` as a where clause and did not provide any arguments, so consequently you got the SQL statement shown in the error.

From the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

```
public int update (String table, ContentValues values, 
                   String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

This one works ...

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Level1", b);
db.update("Game", values, "Level1=?", new String[] {a} );
db.close();
```

... if this is the resulting SQL you want to execute:

```
update Game SET Level1=? WHERE Level1 = 'Test1'
```

Comment: When I set String[] {a}, I can don't run my app. Because it is red underlined. And why do you use "Level1=?", what do you mean with that?

Comment: Thank u so much! it works. But can you explain, why do you use "Level1=?",because I don't understand.

Comment: The statement I build would only update those rows, where the column `Level1` is equal to the value of `a`. If you want to update all rows in your table, you could just use `db.update("Game", values, null, null);`. `?`is a bind variable and for any `?`you provide in the where clause, you need a String value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

`update Game SET Level1=? WHERE Test1.`

Where Test1 is.. what? Where is the conditional part of your update statement. It's expecting something like:

`update Game SET Level1=? WHERE ColumnName='Test1'`

---

Taken from [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) website:

`If the UPDATE statement does not have a WHERE clause, all rows in the table are modified by the UPDATE. Otherwise, the UPDATE affects only those rows for which the result of evaluating the WHERE clause expression as a boolean expression is true.`

A String on it's own is in no way a boolean expression.